Google sites has security certificate for the www subdomain but not for the domain apex
I have a Google site and an HTTP domain. I was told I did not need SSL because Google Sites implements their own. The problem is every URL (www.example.com, example.com, HTTP://WWW.example.com, HTTPS://www.example.com) all work fine. HTTPS://example.com, which is what my Google search link points to does not. It times out.
I've been in sites help forums, search help forums and spent an hour in chat with my registrar with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Is it a classic Google site or a new one (as of 2023)? If you can't edit it, it's classic.

I am late to the party. I apologize. It's a new (not classic) Google site.

The security is working fine, you do not need your own certificate.  But the certificate already installed is for https://www.example.com and not for https://example.com.
You need to have a redirection to change the 2nd url to the first.  If you have access to htaccess, you can do it in there.  If you have access to any tools such as cpanel, you may be able to do it there.
Or change all you references to the url, so that they contain www.

Google sites does not offer cpanel or htaccess.  It is a web site builder that forces you to use their tool to construct your website.  It is more similar to Wix than to Apache shared hosting.

I can do this at my registrar can't I? Oh, and thank you very much. You've been more help than anywhere I've tried.
